# Can't remove bold effect from a p tag

Tags: html, css

I cant seem to remove the bold effect on my p tags. Where the address appears, I want that to be in normal case. Any help on how to do it. Thank You. Link to the page is - http://www.penninetoolsaerospace.com/

Also how do I make the paragraphs closer to each other?

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Pennine Tools Aerospace LTD - Website Coming Soon</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<meta name="keywords" content="Pennine Aerospace" />

<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>

<!--css-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<!--/css-->

<!--fonts-->

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!--fonts-->



</head>

<body>

<div class="container1">

        <!-----start-wrap----->



            <!-----start-Content----->

<div class="content-header">

                    <img src="images/aerospace_logo.png" title="Pennine Tools Aerospace LTD Official Logo" alt="Pennine Tools Official Logo">

                    <p style="color:black; font-size: 28px;">New Website Coming Soon</p><p></p>

                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                    <p>&nbsp;</p>


        <p style="color:black;">For all queries please contact</p><br>

     <p style="color: black;">Email: <a href="mailto:enquiries@penninetoolsaerospace.com">enquiries@penninetoolsaerospace.com</a></p>

    <p style="color:black;">Tel: 01282 815555</p>    

    <p>&nbsp;</p>


    <p style="color: black;;">Pennine Tools Aerospace Ltd</p>
    <p style="color: black;">Unit 1</p>
    <p style="color: black;">Ravenscroft Business Park</p>
    <p style="color: black;">Jackdaw Road</p>
    <p style="color: black;">Barnoldswick</p>
    <p style="color: black;">Lancashire</p>
    <p style="color: black;">BB18 6DX</p>

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the CSS -

/*---start-content-header----*/

.content-header h1{

```
color: #fff;

font-size: 4em;

font-weight: inherit;
```

}

.content-header p{

```
color: #fff;

font-size: 1em;

font-weight: inherit;

word-spacing: 0.2em;
```

}

```
.content-header {

    text-align: center;

    margin-top: 0em;

}

.content-header {

        margin-top: 0em;

    }
```

@media(max-width:1024px){

```
.content-header h1 {

    color: #fff;

    font-size: 3.4em;

    margin:0 0 0.3em 0;

}

.notify {

    width: 50%;

}
```

}

@media(max-width:768px){

```
.content-header h1 {

    font-size: 2.5em;

    margin: 0 0 0.2em;

}

.content-header p {

    color: #fff;

    font-size: 0.85em;

}

.notify {

    width: 57%;

}

.notify input[type="text"] {

    width: 71%;

}
```

}

@media(max-width:640px){

```
.content-header h1 {

    font-size: 0em;

}

.notify {

    width: 75%;

}
```

}

@media(max-width:480px){

```
.content-header h1 {

    font-size: 1.5em;

    margin:0 0 0.5em;

}

.content-header p {

    font-size: 0.8em;

    line-height: 1.6em;

}

.notify {

    width: 71%;

    padding: 1em;

    margin-top: 1em;

}

.notify input[type="text"] {

    width: 52%;

}

.copy-right p {

    font-size: 0.7em;

}
```

}

@media(max-width:320px){

```
.content-header h1 {

    font-size: 1.2em;

    margin: 0 0 0.5em;

    line-height: 1.6em;

}

/*.content-header p {

    font-size: 0.7em;

    line-height: 1.6em;

}*/

.content-header {

    margin-top: 0em;

}

.notify {

    width: 77%;

}
```

}

Comment: the link to the page is - http://www.penninetoolsaerospace.com/

Comment: Your font-weight property seems fine. You just need to reduce font-size of those p tags. Say 0.9 or 0.8em

Comment: You don't bold on your p tags you should reduce the font as @ Nandita Arora Sharma suggested

Comment: I tried changing it but still doesnt remove the bold effect. Only makes it smaller in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your font family has only bold style font. so you need normal style font of this version. if it available in this font family.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved me. Thanks Again.

Comment: Sorry but how do I make the paragraphs closer to each other?

Comment: You need to download Normal style font for this font family. If available

Comment: Thank you for your help.